# How to send money into someone's paypal anonymously ? Read further

Tags: india, cryptocurrency, paypal, japan

I am an Indian and i want to send a Japanese friend some money. The friend uses Paypal and is not familiar about Crypto.
I want to do it anonymously as i can't let anyone know about it. Here in India, we will have to register our PAN number ( a govt. Id) in Paypal to transfer/receive funds. So i can't do it by my Paypal.

Is there any other workaround ?

Last resort would be to open a crypto account for the friend.

Comment: Possibly different situation, but related: [How may I gift/send money to a friend anonymously?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/103534/how-may-i-gift-send-money-to-a-friend-anonymously)

Comment: Is it illegal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deposit crypto into P2P trading platforms such as [Paxful](https://paxful.com/sell-tether/paypal/?paymentMethod=paypal&countryIso=WORLDWIDE&hasScroll=true) and then sell it to your friend's PayPal account. I do not have an account and had to pay a friend in Mexico using PayPal as that was the only payment method he accepts, so I moved USDT onto Paxful and sold it there.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. So i move USDT into paxful and sell it , the proceeds gets credited in friend's paypal , right ?

Comment: @investtech, yes, if you list your friend's email as the PayPal payment account. However, it would be better if your friend is online and can confirm that he has received the payment

Comment: Perfect. I can't thank you enough for this. Just setup my Paxful. Its what i was searching the whole day. 
Thanks :)